# ESP8266-12E and MCP23017 , unable to identify the application

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, esp8266, i2c

After googling much I have found that MCP23017 can be used with esp8266-12e for more number of output pins. 
I have tried all the programs from different tutorials on internet but could not make it work.

Basically my question is , i want to control all the 16 leds connected to GPA0-7 AND GPB0-7 individually , hence i need a program snippet for make it work.
I am using AP mode for esp8266-12e and sending get methods with params to identify which led to turn on/off.

Even i have written the basic program , can anyone help me completing the entire program. thanks for the help in advanced.

Pins i have connected are

```
ESP8266-12E    |   MCP23017
−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
GPIO-14 (scl)  |  PIN-12 (SCL)
GPIO-2 (sda)   |  PIN 13 (SDA)
GND            |  A0,A1,A2
```

My code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void handleRoot() {
    server.send(200, "text/html", "<h1>You are connected</h1>");
}

void setup() {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Configuring access point...");
    WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

    IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
    Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
    Serial.println(myIP);
    server.on("/", handleRoot);

    server.on("/led1", [](){});
    server.on("/led2", [](){});
    server.on("/led3", [](){});
    server.on("/led4", [](){});
    // up to 16 leds i have written same method.

    server.begin();
}

void loop() {
    server.handleClient();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an MCP23017 which connects to the device using the I2C protocol, which means you need the  library.  You also need to ensure that SCL and SDA are 'pulled up' using 4.7Kohm resistors between the data lines and the +ve line.
You will then need to send commands to the device to initialise it and set the pins to OUTPUT.  (See http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21952b.pdf).

When running you will need to update the state of this pins by sending messages such as  0x09 0xFF to turn them all on.

It is going to be worth looking for a library that already does all this, but writing your own shouldn't be too hard.  You will be able to use an Arduino library on an ESP8266.

These chips are the easiest ones to use and learn about I2C, so its worth looking at the manual and trying to write your own "library" (Just start by writing a C++ class within your sketch folder.)

Comment: A very useful link and the description you have provided Matt.
I need to read and understand whats written in the docs and implement it. it will take time for me to do it. But thanks for the guidance. I think i will need more ahead.

Comment: hi , i tried to connect 4.7k and 22k resistors for sda , scl 
sda --22k-- Vcc(+5v) And 
scl --22k-- vcc(+5v)
but still not getting anything.
i have been trying to program this since a lot of days , but not be able to do it. 
can u please help me more in this.
i am using this code in arduino
https://github.com/pedrominatel/esp8266-arduino-examples/blob/master/mcp23017/mcp23017_esp8266.cpp

Comment: the changes in this example i have done are line 152 : MCP23017_init(u8_MCP23017_address, 4,5);
i tried this too becuase in some datasheets it has 4=sda and 5=scl

Comment: any guidance please.

Comment: Step 1 Try using I2CScanner http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner rather than your own code to make sure that the hardware is functioning.  ESP pins number in the code do not match the pin number on the boards usually.  Find an image (on Google) of your ESP board with the pin numbers listed and use the GPIO_n numbers.

Comment: i tried 4 i2cscanner programs , but none of them are detecting the  i2c address. also tried to connect wires to different pins for trial and error , still not working. 
please guide.

Comment: If I2CScanner can't find it you either have a circuit wiring problem, or faulty hardware.  Just use  the Arduino and MCP IC and minimal wires and 2 pull up resistors.

Comment: Wired whole thing again. 
the result in i2c scanner i got is ; 
I2C device found at address 0x38  !
whats next???

Comment: @KarmaCoding - Now you need to write a handler function for you on handlers to call.  You could do it from scratch http://tronixstuff.com/2011/08/26/tutorial-maximising-your-arduinos-io-ports/ or you could use a library https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MCP23017-Arduino-Library.  All you are doing is sending a one byte address and some data to the chip (using wire.write) and you should have flashing Leds in no time.  Once you get the hang of this you will understand just about all I2C devices.